# find back old Ubuntu entry for grub

Tags: boot, grub2

I am using OpenSuse as my first os to boot, I tried to make grub boot a previous Ubuntu entry but it disappeared after `sudo nano /boot/grub/grub.conf`   , how can I make it visible for grub again ?
The physical location was on the same disk as my OpenSuse entry.

Comment: To me your question is off-topic, as it sounds like `grub` is controlled by a non-Ubuntu OpenSuSE system. If you refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and *official* flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.  I'd suggest running `update-grub` on opensuse to see if it detects the Ubuntu system & work from there; however that command differs on OpenSuSE, so your question belongs on SE *Unix & Linux* as I see site rules sorry (*even though it's Ubuntu you're trying to boot*)

Comment: @guiverc It seems that OP wants to revive an Ubuntu installation whicch does not show up in GRUB. We don't know whether the installation is overwritten. However, this does not seem to be off topic.

Comment: The command `sudo nano /boot/grub/grub.conf` would simply open that file for editing (or creates a blank file for editing if that file didn't already exist) using the `nano` editor. That command does not delete grub entries unless YOU deleted them AND saved your changes. Obviously, we need to see the contents of the file that you changed to  determined if you deleted lines or merely commented them out. If you were following some sort of instructions when you opened the editor, a link to those instructions would be very helpful.

Comment: https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/531534-Update-Grub was the instruction I used. After that my Ubuntu entry vanished.

Comment: thanks for answering anyway, @guiverc and not thanks to the "helpfull" persons trying to downvote my question being off topic. As for me I would never do that.